# Servlet invocation using annotations

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have used **register** as the name of the servlet and to be invoked when submit button is clicked. However, it is not invoked I have added all jar files. please someone can help me with this error. I am just started learning backend.

**jsp Code**

```
<form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/register" method="post">
   <table style="with: 80%">
    <tr>
     <td>First Name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Last Name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

**Servlet Code**

```
@WebServlet("/register")
public class EmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private EmployeeDao employeedao=new EmployeeDao();
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public EmployeeServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/User.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Employee employee=new Employee();
        employee.setFirst_name(request.getParameter("firstname"));
        employee.setLast_name(request.getParameter("lastname"));
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/after_regestration.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

Comment: Did  you try a simple  "Hello World " Servlet?   It would be easier to debug that first.  Which  Servlet container are you using? Tomcat? what version?  Please  show us your web app's web.xml file. Any errors in logs?

Comment: Tomcat servlet container version 10. if we use annotation then we don't need to use a web.xml file is that right. There are no errors in error log

Comment: A web.xml file is not necessary for a working web app. But, if you want to use  annotations  then  you might have to provide one.  I think you need to  include  the  following attribute in your web.xml file's root tag;   metadata-complete="false"

Comment: I know that at  https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#annotations-and-pluggability    it is stated  "If the metadata-complete attribute is not specified, or its value is false, the deployment tool must examine the class files of the application for such annotations."    But, I  didn't find that  to be true. My annotations were not found  unless  I specified  it.

Comment: Read at  https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#inclusion-of-a-web-xml-deployment-descriptor   "A web application is NOT required to contain a web.xml if it does NOT contain any servlet, filter, or listener components or is using annotations to declare the same. In other words an application containing only static files or JSP pages does not require a web.xml to be present."

Comment: If my comments are useful to you, then I will include them in an answer.